# Issue in using Annotate Plugin(Annox) with "cxf-codegen-plugin"

Tags: web-services, jaxb2, annox, cxf-xjc-plugin

I am developing RESTFul services in my application. We are using '**cxf-codegen-plugin**' to generate the JAXB classes from the schema. For a given requirement, I need to add some annotation to the generated JAXB classes and I was trying to use **Annotate Plugin(Annox)** for this but having issue in using it. I am getting **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Using "http://annox.dev.java.net" customizations requires the "-Xannotate" switch to enable this plug-in.**

This is how I have the setup in my codebase:
1. The WSDL refer to a XSD where I have the definitions of annotations.
2. pom.xml is using 'cxf-codegen-plugin' to generate the jabx classes.
3. The RESTFul service need some additional annotation on the generated classes, so I am trying ti use Annox to get the work done.

This is the snippet from the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="gov.nih.nci.po.webservices.types"
    xmlns:tns="gov.nih.nci.po.webservices.types" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:ja="http://annox.dev.java.net/org.codehaus.jackson.annotate"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd
                        http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox">    

    <complexType name="PersonRole" abstract="true">
        <annotation>
            <appinfo>
                <annox:annotate>                    
                     <ja:JsonTypeInfo use="CLASS" include="PROPERTY" property="@class"/>
                </annox:annotate>                
            </appinfo>
        </annotation>
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="tns:Role">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="personId" type="long" />
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>  
</schema>
```

and this is how I want my generated class to look like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PersonRole", propOrder = { "personId" })
@XmlSeeAlso({ HealthCareProvider.class, OrganizationalContact.class,
        ClinicalResearchStaff.class })
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class PersonRole extends Role {
```

And below is the entry from pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/PersonService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg>                                                                                                           </extraargs>                                    
                                </wsdlOption>                              
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>                   
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>                   
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Also I noticed that if I give some wrong value/configuration in xsd under **JsonTypeInfo** section, the build fail & complains (like mandatory field 'use' is missing etc) -- so I am assuming that the Annox plug-in is enabled & trying to do something. but then when I use above configurations, the build is failing with SAXParseException: Using "http://annox.dev.java.net" customizations requires the "-Xannotate" switch to enable this plug-in.

Could anybody please suggest as how this can be fixed?

Comment: The issue is resolved. I was having different WSDLs using the same XSD(which has Annox changes) but then I enabled the plugin in only one service, so basically it was complaining for other WSDLs. Once I enabled the plug-in for other WSDLs, it started working.